# TinyMCE Toolbar Not Showing For Anonymous Users

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have custom Dexterity types: [Folder](https://github.com/l34marr/tbfac.content/blob/master/tbfac/content/folder.py) is folderish, [Article](https://github.com/l34marr/tbfac.content/blob/master/tbfac/content/article.py) is to be addable in that folder. In addition, Article is addable by anonymous users. For quick testing, I modify the folder's Security Settings in ZMI, turning on `Add portal content` permission for `Anonymous` role.

Somehow, now that anonymous user can add Article, but TinyMCE toolbar does not show, that is working well when the login user adding Article. Seems that TinyMCE toolbar needs more settings for the anonymous user. Any hints?

[image: TinyMCE Toolbar not Showing When Anonymous User Adding the Type]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just because tiny MCE's javascript is loaded only for authenticated users.
To make it available for all, go to ZMI -> portal_javascript, search for tiny_mce, and uncheck "Restrict to authenticated users?" checkbox.

This will do the trick.

Comment: How do we do this for plone 5?

Comment: In Plone 5, `mockup-patterns-tinymce` is registered in the [++resource++plone-logged-in.js](http://demo.plone.de/++resource++plone-logged-in.js) resource from `plone-logged-in` bundle. If you move it to the `plone` bundle, that is, the [++resource++plone.js](http://demo.plone.de/++resource++plone.js), you'll get it. Alternatively you can register `mockup-patterns-tinymce` resource into your package bundle or insert it on a per template base with [add_resource_on_request()](http://docs.plone.org/adapt-and-extend/theming/resourceregistry.html#controlling-resource-and-bundle-rendering).